# update a table view with new data on click of a button

Tags: c#, uitableview, uibutton, xamarin

I have a textfield (ziptext) that takes in a zipcode and I need to, onclick of a button(submit), convert that zipcode is converted into latitude and longitude coordinates and then search for all nearby locations of a store and populates the table view (zipcode) with results.

```
public List<String[]> Adresses { get; set; }
public List<String[]> SpecAdresses;

public ZipController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    Adresses = new List<String[]> ();
    SpecAdresses = new List<String[]> ();
}

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    Zipcode.RegisterClassForCellReuse (typeof(UITableViewCell), callHistoryCellId);
    Zipcode.Source = new CallHistoryDataSource (this);      
    Submit.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        CLGeocoder latlng = new CLGeocoder ();
        latlng.GeocodeAddress (Ziptext.Text, HandleCLGeocodeCompletionHandler);
    };
}

void HandleCLGeocodeCompletionHandler (CLPlacemark[] placemarks, NSError error)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < placemarks.Length; i++)
    {
        lat = placemarks [i].Location.Coordinate.Latitude;
        lng = placemarks [i].Location.Coordinate.Longitude;
    }
    Console.WriteLine (lat.ToString() + ":" + lng.ToString());
}

/**
Methods to sort though the list and find stores with in close proximity
**/

class CallHistoryDataSource : UITableViewSource
{
    ZipController controller;

    public CallHistoryDataSource (ZipController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    // Returns the number of rows in each section of the table
    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, int section)
    {
        return controller.SpecAdresses.Count;
    }
    //
    // Returns a table cell for the row indicated by row property of the NSIndexPath
    // This method is called multiple times to populate each row of the table.
    // The method automatically uses cells which have scrolled off the screen or creates new ones as necessary.
    //
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        CustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (ZipController.ZipId) as CustomCell;
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = new CustomCell (ZipController.ZipId);
        }

        int row = indexPath.Row;
        string[] t = controller.SpecAdresses [row];

        cell.UpdateCell (//------//);
        return cell;
    }


    public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 80.0f;
    }
}
```

I've managed to convert the zipcode and find all nearby locations. But, i don't know how to make it so that the table view will be updated on each click of the button. In other words, i need the table to refresh it's data with every click of submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the TouchUpInside event of the Submit button -> you want to do the following things:

1. Update the data source (Give the table the "new" data source)
2. Reload Data on the "table" (Refresh the table so that it reads from the "data" source)

You already pass a reference to your controller when you create the CallHistoryDataSource, so all you need to do is update the SpecAdreses list with the data you want to display and reload the table data.

Some code:

```
    Submit.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    CLGeocoder latlng = new CLGeocoder ();
    latlng.GeocodeAddress (Ziptext.Text, HandleCLGeocodeCompletionHandler);

     // add code here to update the SpecAdresses list with the data you want to display

    Zipcode.ReloadData() // refresh the table
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the underlying data of your table's source (which it appears that you are already doing), then all you should have to do is call

```
TableView.ReloadData();
```

in your controller to tell the TableView that it needs to refresh itself